# Regex for replacing a symbol after a certain number of repititions

Tags: regex, r

I've been given a CSV-file that is semicolon delimited. However the last column contains free text which contains semicolons.

```
frank; 1; 103; his name is frank
alice; 2; 09; sometimes; she says hi
kim; 3; 123; bla;bla;bla;
```

The first three semicolons are used to separate my columns, the rest however 
are must be replaced with `--`. Is there a way I can do this with regular expressions? I keep running into problems because look-behinds must be fixed-length. The result should look like this:

```
frank; 1; 103; his name is frank
alice; 2; 09; sometimes-- she says hi
kim; 3; 123; bla--bla--bla--
```

I'm using R's PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non regex solution using `strsplit`.

```
data <- c("frank; 1; 103; his name is frank",
          "alice; 2; 09; sometimes; she says hi",
          "kim; 3; 123; bla;bla;bla;")
front <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(data, ";"), "[", 1:3), 
                function(x)paste(x, collapse=";"))
back <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(data, ";"), "[", -(1:3)), 
               function(x)paste(x, collapse="--"))
> paste(front, back, sep=";")
[1] "frank; 1; 103; his name is frank"     
[2] "alice; 2; 09; sometimes-- she says hi"
[3] "kim; 3; 123; bla--bla--bla"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb based on your description and guess that you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Since you are writing in terms of "columns", with a semicolon as a delimiter, but possibly also as a value only in the third column, then I would suggest you try something like `separate` from "tidyr" or `stri_split_fixed` from "stringi".

This is what those approaches would look like, with the following sample data:

```
myString <- c("frank; 1; 103; his name is frank", 
              "alice; 2; 09; sometimes; she says hi",
              "kim; 3; 123; bla;bla;bla;")
```

#### "Stringi"

```
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(myString, ";", n = 3, simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]    [,2] [,3]                         
# [1,] "frank" " 1" " 103; his name is frank"    
# [2,] "alice" " 2" " 09; sometimes; she says hi"
# [3,] "kim"   " 3" " 123; bla;bla;bla;"
```

#### "dplyr" + "tidyr"

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_frame(myString) %>%
  separate(myString, into = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), extra = "merge")
# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# 
#      V1    V2                         V3
#   (chr) (chr)                      (chr)
# 1 frank     1     103; his name is frank
# 2 alice     2 09; sometimes; she says hi
# 3   kim     3          123; bla;bla;bla;
```